# How to calculate absent_over_time with label dimensional?

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have a counter, for example, `user_actions` with label `user_id`. I want to get alert, when `user_actions` is disappeared for any `user_id`.

Literally, I need `absent_over_time(user_actions[60m])`, but taking into account `user_id` label.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with PromQL solution for this task, but it can be implemented with `lag()` function from MetricsQL. For instance, the following query would return all the `user_actions` time series that have no data points during the last 5 minutes (see `5*60` in the query). The query stops noticing such time series after 60 minutes (see `60m` in square brackets):

```
lag(user_actions[60m]) > 5*60
```

See more details about `lag()` function in [MetricsQL docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).

Comment: am I right, that I cannot use this solution in Prometheus, but instead I should use VictoriaMetrics?

Comment: Correct - Prometheus doesn't support `lag` function yet

Comment: I see, thank you. VictoriaMetrics is a great project, but right now I have Prometheus :(